# Deleting cookie wp_woocommerce_session_ for not logged users with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, session, cookies

My problem is I have woocommerce action addToCart() which verifies nonce from POST - if user is not logged if he chooses product first time nonce is verfied and everything works, but after that nonce can't be verifed, deleting wp_woocommerce_session cookie seems to fix this problem, but I dont want to delete it for logged users so I can't use JS for this, I tried using

`WC()->session->forget_session()` and `WC()->session->destroy_session()`

But this functions deletes all cookies like woocommerce_hash_cart and woocommerce_items_in_cart

```
 if($_COOKIE) {
                foreach ($_COOKIE as $key=>$val)
                {
                   if(str_contains($key,"wp_woocommerce_session_")){
                       unset($_COOKIE[$key]);
                       wc_setcookie($key, '', time()-3600);
                       setcookie($key, '', time()-3600);
                   }
                }
            }
```

But sadly it doesn't work, do you have any idea how can i remove just this one Cookie?

Comment: Your question needs more context.  Where are you hooking this function? If it's after `init` then headers are already sent, and you won't be able to modify cookies with PHP.

Comment: Yes i hooked it to init, I resolved this problem by myself, i deleted all caching on my site then i added if statement to ajax call if nonce is not verifed then reload site with no cache, and everything seems fine now i didnt even needed to use this code that i added to my post :)

Answer (score 0):

Deleting all caching modules and adding if statement to ajax call which checks if nonce is not verifed if its true then reload window location with no cache works just fine :)